# How to dynamically alter tsconfig compilerOptions.paths?

Tags: typescript, webpack

Using Webpack 3.x, Typescript 2.x, Awesome Typescript loader 2.x

I need to dynamically mirror my computed value in webpack's resolve.alias property in typescript's compilerOptions.paths property at compile time.

The aliases can be different per build which works great for webpack, but falls down when it comes to resolving those aliases when typechecking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with webpack to typscript aliasing, I managed to solve this by just writing my aliases to tsconfig with a gulp task.

```
  let jsonAliases = myGetterFunctionForAliases(),
    path = 'tsconfig.json',
    tsconfig = require(`tsconfig.json`);

  for(let prop in jsonAliases) {
    jsonAliases[prop] = [`${jsonAliases[prop]}`]
  }

  tsconfig.compilerOptions.paths = jsonAliases;

  customNodeStuff.writeJSONFile(path, tsconfig);
```